# DocuSign API creating an envelope in a specific folder

Tags: docusignapi

i am able to create an envelope with the DocuSign api. according to the documentation there is the attribute to specify the folderid in which you want to put the envelope. i have tried many things and the envelope never goes to the specified folder it only goes to the sent folder. how do we make sure the envelope is created in the specified folder id? there seems to be no sample code / syntax on how to do this via the documentation.

i've tried folder.folderId and folder[0].folderId and folders[0].folderId

```
[
    {
        "emailSubject": "This request is sent from a Template",
        "emailBlurb": "Please sign...thanks!",
        "templateId": "hidden",
        "envelopeIdStamping": "false",
        "templateRoles": [
            {
                "roleName": "Signer 1",
                "name": "Matt",
                "email": "email@email.com",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "tabs": {
                    "textTabs": [
                        {
                            "tabLabel": "dateField",
                            "value": "July 19, 2019"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "folders": [
            {
                "folderId": "folderIDhere"
            }
        ],
        "status": "sent"
    }
]
```

no errors at all it just doesnt save in the folder

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that you can create an envelope directly into a folder. I believe you'll need to take the Envelope ID you get in response to the Envelope Creation call, then plug it in to a [Folders::MoveEnvelopes](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Folders/Folders/moveEnvelopes) call like so:

`PUT /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/folders/{folderId}`

```
{
  "envelopeIds": [
    "{envelope_id}"
  ],
}
```

Comment: I think Drew is correct. I would add that anything you can do from our web app, you should be able to do via the API. Try to do this via the UI first. I don't think that's possible either. Envelopes are always created the same way and you can only move them after they are created. But I may be wrong, so please check....